# How to treat disposal of rental property appliance

Tags: rental-property

I disposed of a broken washing machine in a rental property and purchased a new one. My question is how to handle the disposal of the old one. Should it show up on form 4797 in Part I or Part III or somewhere else? If on 4797 should it have $0 sale value (it was fully depreciated and I received no $ for it). Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are in the US, better add a country tag, it will be handled like any other equipment/asset that depreciates, is discarded and replaced, you don't need to do anything beyond that - unless you are doing all this manually. Most tax/ledger software (such as TurboTax / Quicken/Quickbooks) will handle the property logistics for you as long as you provide the data needed in a timely manner and answer the questions that relate to it correctly. If you are doing it manually, you really should look into some on hand legal tax advice instead.

Answer (score 2):

It was fully depreciated. So its value was zero. You don't account for it, you just add the new one and depreciate it over its useful life.